# Translating user-feedback message of custom PloneFormGen validator

Tags: internationalization, plone, ploneformgen, plone-4.x

I have a [PloneFormGen custom field-input validator](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/ploneformgen/custom_validators.html) whose user-feedback message I'd like to translate. How can I do this? I use a [Python Script as validator](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/ploneformgen/custom_validators.html#using-a-python-script), so in the example as given by the documentation...

```
if 'spam' in value.lower():
    return False
else:
    return "'%s' doesn't seem to have spam. Try again." % value
```

...how would I change to translate `return "'%s' doesn't seem to have spam. Try again." % value` to have it return the translated string?

I already have my own `locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/myproduct.po` file that I already use for translating page templates. I could just extend this file with some `msgid` and `msgstr` lines by hand. The validator currently lives as a Python Script in `portal_skins/custom/` and was just quickly created Through The Web (TTW) but I could also move it my product if definitely necessary.

I've read http://developer.plone.org/i18n/internationalisation.html, but this page is so overwhelming and referring to all kinds of types and versions that I still do not know how to do it for this very purpose. I use Plone 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation via locale files might be possible, but might require writing a browser view so that you can get access to the message factory machinery.

But if you don't need that you could try simply embedding the translations in the script and testing request.LANGUAGE to determine the response.

```
if request.LANGUAGE == 'en-us':
    return "Try again yank!"
elif REQUEST.LANGUAGE ...
```